# likert scales analysis - testing age+sex and each question at the time

Tags: correlation, likert, spearman-rho

This is the first time I conducted survey and I am having trouble deciding on the right analysis to apply. It is an exploratory survey, aiming to test visitors' motivation to protect wildlife vs connection/knowledge about animals.

I have 16 questions. The responses are on a Likert scale (from ‘strongly disagree‘ to ‘strongly agree‘ with 7 levels).
I want to calculate the correlations between each of the questions/columns. It would be nice to also correlate sex and age.

My data goes like this:

```
Participant Age Sex Quest a Quest b Quest c Quest d Quest e Quest f Quest g
Respondent 1    20s F   7   5   4   5   5   4   4
Respondent 2    50s F   6   6   4   5   6   4   4
Respondent 3    30s M   5   6   4   4   5   2   4
Respondent 4    20s F   6   6   2   5   6   2   5
Respondent 5    60s M   5   4   4   5   5   2   4
```

(and so on for the 520 respondents).

If I understood it correctly, Spearman can only correlate two columns at the same time but I want to correlate age+sex+question A, then age+sex+question B, then age+sex+question C+... and so on.

What would be the best way to do this in R?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can use regression analysis. For instance, QA will be your outcome, and age and sex your predictors. You can also include an interaction term between age and sex. But since you are leaving bivariate framework, you need to be careful. Another (maybe simpler) option is to stratify the sample by sex, and then to check correlation between QA and age, etc. But I think full sample analysis is better.

Comment: Since you have 16 variables which interrelations you are interested in, an alternative way would be to use principal components or factor analysis or some other data reduction technique, and then check the resulting dimensions relations with age and sex.